# android graphview touch event

Tags: android, android-graphview

I was finally able to get android [GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos) up and running. However when I try to scroll or zoom nothing happens. I've tried using ScrollView, LinearLayout, and a host of others. I'm currently loading the graph in a DialogFragment.

```
package com.example.resistograph;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView;

public class GraphFragment extends DialogFragment {
static String data;
int[] conversion;

public GraphFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] lines = data.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
    conversion = new int[lines.length];

     for(int i=1; i<lines.length; i=i+1){
         conversion[i]=Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);
     }

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_fragment, container, false);

    GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = null;

    for (int x=0; x<lines.length; x=x+1) {
        exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
                new GraphViewData(x, conversion[x]),
        });
    }

    GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
              getActivity() // context
              , "GraphViewDemo" // heading
        );
    graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data
    graphView.setScalable(true);
    graphView.setScrollable(true);  
    graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setHorizontalLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
    graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setVerticalLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.graph);

    layout.addView(graphView);
    return v;
}   
}
```

My layout file looks like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/graph"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</LinearLayout>
```

When I go to scroll or zoom the eclipse log says this:

```
09-20 23:45:36.380: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+0.0
09-20 23:45:36.440: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+0.0
09-20 23:45:36.460: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+615.3957
09-20 23:45:36.470: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+613.4519
09-20 23:45:36.480: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+608.0
09-20 23:45:36.510: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+0.0
09-20 23:45:36.540: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+601.4615
09-20 23:45:36.580: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+598.99097
09-20 23:45:36.600: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+593.62683
09-20 23:45:37.770: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+0.0
09-20 23:45:37.770: D/GraphView(12160): on touch event scale not handled+508.0
```

Comment: do the graphview examples work for you?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to put `graphView.setViewPort(value1, value2);`